# App Crashes Converting UIImage to PDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Apple rejected my app with this report:

http://nopaste.me/paste/173567898450806a3c774c4

I cannot reproduce using the same device and iOS as they mention i.e. iPad 3 iOS6.

They refer to the functionality that converts image into PDF and email it. I use this block of code to do so:

```
-(IBAction)didPressSaveToPDFButton:(id)sender{

   NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, imageView.bounds, nil);
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
   CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [imageView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

   NSLog(@"PDF");

   MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [vc setSubject:@"PDF"];
   [vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"mypdf.pdf"];

   [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Does anybody see what the report points to and/or where the error is? I cannot see what's wrong.

Symbolicated report:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x35e9729e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d1f97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x327e213c -[UIViewController     presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3760
3   UIKit                           0x32904252 -[UIViewController         presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
4   MyAppName                           0x0009c5a2 -[ViewController didPressSaveToPDFButton:] (ViewController.m:200)
5   UIKit                           0x327e10a8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
6   UIKit                           0x327e1130 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 116
```

Comment: have you symbolicated the crash report?

Comment: what does it mean? this is the first rejection I ever get so I am not familiar with the process.

Comment: @Vad That's OK to get the first rejection, crash logs symbolication is widely discussed at internet, a quick search will easily give you a good article to get familiar with it. What you will have then is the exact place in the code where the app crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you didn't symbolicate your crash log it's pretty tough to tell what's happening. My guess is that that your pdfContext is coming out nil and you are trying to render your imageView in a layer with a nil context.

I would try

```
 if (pdfContext) {
   [imageView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
 }
 else {
   return;
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the fact that it is single thread and mail composer needs to be open with a slight delay.